# How can I statistically compare two time-series?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, spss, minitab

I have two time-series.
Data have been logged over time for two different objects.
Is there a significance test, applicable in SPSS or Minitab, that can be used to determine whether there is a significant difference between my objects? The data are acquired at the same frequency.